# How to assign different background colors before and after an element only with html and scss?

Tags: html, css, sass

I made a circle with CSS and gave it a class called `node`. Then I used `::after`to create a centered line on this circle.

I'm trying to assign different colors to each side of this circle. So say left side of the circle should have a line with grey color and right side of the circle should have a line with blue color.

I need 10 reps to upload an image so I tried to explain the situation.

I have tried to use `::before` and `::after` to determine what color to be used but I couldn't make it happen.

```css
.node,
.node-second,
.node-last,
.node-first {
  background-color: #b2cae9;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.node::after {
  content: "";
  right: -50%;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid #b2cae9;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="timeline-wrapper d-flex flex-row align-items-center ">
  <div class="timeline-child active d-flex flex-column align-items-center flex-grow-1">
    <span class="date">18.01.2019</span>
    <span class="node-first"></span>
    <span class="text">Lorem İpsum Dot</span>
  </div>
  <div class="timeline-child active d-flex flex-column  align-items-center flex-grow-1">
    <span class="date">18.01.2019</span>
    <span class="node"></span>
    <span class="text">Lorem İpsum Dot</span>
  </div>
  <div class="timeline-child d-flex flex-column  align-items-center flex-grow-1">
    <span class="date">18.01.2019</span>
    <span class="d-flex flex-grow-1 node"></span>
    <span class="text">Lorem İpsum Dot</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would it make sense to make the lines separate elements from the nodes entirely?

Comment: use this website to upload u r img https://imgur.com/upload.  upload it and attach the  link

Answer (score 1):

You can try it like this. I have used the circle element,  `:before` element for the grey line and `:after` element for the blue line and positioned it accordingly. You were missing the `:before` element in your code. I had to write CSS since the snippet does not support SASS here but you can use this tool to convert it to SASS: https://css2sass.herokuapp.com/

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.circle {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid black; /* Show the Circle */
  position: relative;
}

.circle:before,
.circle:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 49vw;
  height: 3px;
  position: absolute;
}

.circle:before {
  border-bottom: 4px solid grey; /* Show the blue line */
  right: 12px;
}

.circle:after {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #B2CAE9; /* Show the grey line */
  left: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="circle">

  </div>
</div>
```